# DocuSign API - Add Signing Page at the end of each Document

Tags: api, docusignapi

I have a requirement to send documents for E-Signing using DocuSign API.The number of documents to be send is dynamic and is decided by admin user of my application.I need to programmatically add a Signature page at the end of each document.

Please do let me know if this possible using the DocuSign API. If yes , can you please provide the steps/sample code to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/features/tabs#tab-placement-method-2-auto-place-anchor-tagging

For instance, let's say we have a document that contains the text "Please Sign Here:". If we want to place a signature tab where this string is found in the document, or better yet place a signature tab 1 inch to the right of the string to make sure the signature does not overwrite it